# Dropping and recreating unexpected primary keys

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have a tool which uses SQL scripts to apply changes to a customer database. Often this invloves changing a column definition (datatype etc). The problem is that often there are primary keys applied by the user that we don't know about (and they don't remember), which trips up the process (eg when changing columns belonging to the indexes or primary keys).

The requirement given to me is that this update process should be 'seamless', with no human involvement to prepare the ground. I have also researched this on this forum, and as far as I can see my particular question has not yet been asked.

I know how to disable and then later rebuild all indexes on a database, and even those only in certain tables, but if the index is on a primary key I still can't change any column that is part of the primary key unless I explicitly drop the PK by name, and later recreate it explicitly, which means I have to know about it at code-time. I can probably write a query to find the name of the primary key on a table if one is there, but how to know how to recreate it?

How can I, using Transact-SQL (or PL/SQL), detect, drop and then recreate the primary keys on given tables, without knowing at code time what they are or what columns belong to them? The key is that the tool cannot know in advance what the primary keys are are on any given table, nor what they comprise. The SQL code must handle this itself.

Better still would be to detect if a known column belongs to a primary key, then drop and later recreate that after I have changed the column.

This needs to be done in both Oracle and Sql Server, ideally purely with SQL code.

TIA

Comment: I really hope that the first statement in your script is BACKUP DATABASE.

Comment: For SQL Server this will get you started: [How do I find the columns of a primary key for a specified table?](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345522.aspx#_FAQ16)

Comment: We advise that the database is always backed up beforehand by a sysadmin. If it is done in the upgrade process we get complaints about time taken, and if the customer chooses to ignore the instructions, that is their own lookout. But that is beside the point of my question, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why would a customer define his own primary keys for the tables? Moreover, I don't understand why would you let them? In my world, if customer changes schema in any way, this automatically means end of support for them.

I will strongly advise against dropping and recreating primary keys on production database. Any number of bad things can happen, leading to data loss.

And it's not just the PKs, you will have to drop the foreign key constraints first. And FKs may reference not only the PKs but the unique constraints as well, so yao have to deal with those as well.

Your best bet would be to create a new table with the required schema, copy the data, drop original table and rename the new one. Of course, you will have to handle the FKs, but it's easier. Check this link an example:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2009/09/17/script-to-create-all-foreign-keys.aspx

Comment: The customer is king, and I have been given an instruction to carry out so I need a technical solution really, politics and good practice aside.

Comment: Just had to say it :) But I believe that I also provided the technical answer as well.

Comment: You did indeed and I thank you. I ws merely stressing that the other aspects are not something I have the luxury of considering in this case.